# Change height of all Pictureboxes C#

Tags: c#, height, picturebox

I ran into a problem when trying to change the size of all PictureBoxes in a project.

The PictureBoxes have been created like this:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++)
                {
                        string filePath = fileEntries[i];
                        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
                        int index = Array.IndexOf(fileEntries, filePath);

                        PictureBox image = new PictureBox();
                        image.Text = filePath;
                        image.Top = (int)y * 185 + 8 + 185;
                        image.Left = (int)x * 325 + 9;
                        image.Name = "picbox";
                        image.Click += picbox_Click;
                        image.Image = Image.FromFile(filePath);
                        image.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 110);
                        image.Height = 181;
                        image.Width = 318;
                        image.Padding = new Padding(2);
                        image.Name = "picbox";
                        this.Controls.Add(image);
                    }
```

Then, when clicking a box, I want to change the height, width, padding and Name of all PictureBoxes on the Form. Currently, I am using the following code:

```
picbox.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 110);
picbox.Height = 177;
picbox.Width = 314;
picbox.Padding = new Padding(0);
picbox.Name = "picboxnew";
```

This is not working, does anyone know how I can make this work?

Kind regards,

Comment: By not working you mean it doesn't compile? Gives a runtime error? Makes no (visible) difference? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it using Linq:

```
var pictureboxes = this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>().ToList();
foreach (PictureBox pb in pictureboxes)
{
    pb.Height = 500;
    pb.Name = "some_name";
    //etc
}
```

Comment: Interesting - why does this work but the OP's code not work?

Comment: @doctorlove I'm guessing because there's no such thing as `picbox` which OP is trying to change...

Comment: @josap you can mark answer as a solution as a way to say thanks :)

Comment: @nino I have maked it as solved, Stackoverflow wouldn't let me do it before, sorry.